# How to set initial value for foldLeft When Using EitherT[Future, Failure, Option[B]]

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats

I am using `EitherT[Future, Failure, Option[B]]` in the following function which does `foldLeft`.  How to set Initial value for `foldLeft` in the code below ?

```
    def doWork[A, B](seq: Set[A])(f: A => EitherT[Future, Failure,  Option[B]]): EitherT[Future, Failure, Set[Option[B]]] = 
        seq.foldLeft(????? how to set this initial value here ????) {
          case (acc, nxt) => acc.flatMap(bs => f(nxt).map(b => bs :+ b))
        }
```

Comment: I suppose you want to start with a `Right(Set.empty)` ?

Comment: Using Right(Set.empty), acc does not have flatMap function to invoke

Comment: If using EitherT.right(Future(Set.empty)), then  found   : cats.data.EitherT[Future,Failure,Seq[Option[B]]]
[error]  required: cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,Nothing,Seq[Nothing]]

Comment: it seems that you mixed `Either` and `Try` monads. What type do you expect to have on left param of `Either` instead of `Failure`? Maybe `Throwable`?

Comment: or `Failure` is just your custom type implemented somewhere?

Comment: Yes. You are right. Failure is my customer type implemented

Comment: You can think Failure as Throwable for the test purpose

Comment: use `EitherT[Future, Failure, Set[Option[B]]](Future.successful(Right(Set())))` but change `bs :+ b` to `bs + b`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
EitherT.rightT[Future, Failure](Set.empty[Option[B]])
```

like so

```
def doWork[A, B](seq: Set[A])(f: A => EitherT[Future, Failure,  Option[B]]): EitherT[Future, Failure, Set[Option[B]]] =
  seq.foldLeft(EitherT.rightT[Future, Failure](Set.empty[Option[B]])) {
    case (acc, nxt) => acc.flatMap(bs => f(nxt).map(b => bs + b))
  }
```

This is a slightly shorter version of Bogdan's suggestion

```
EitherT[Future, Failure, Set[Option[B]]](Future.successful(Right(Set())))
EitherT.rightT[Future, Failure](Set.empty[Option[B]])
```

Comment: Which package defined EitherT.rightT ? I use import cats.data.EitherT, but does not have rightT

Comment: Yes that should be the correct import: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html#from-a-or-b-to-eithertf-a-b You will also have to follow Bogdan’s suggestion and change the operator.